# Postgis: create column with srid in procedure

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql, alter-table, generated-columns

Hello,

I wonder how I could create a spatialized column with an srid retrieved from the db.

```sql
-- OK --
ALTER TABLE POI ADD COORDS GEOMETRY(POINT, 26916);

-- KO (invalid input syntax for type integer: "sridval") --
DO $$
DECLARE
    sridval int;
BEGIN
    sridval := (select srid FROM project_options);
    ALTER TABLE POI ADD COORDS GEOMETRY(POINT, sridval);
END$$;

-- OK but verbose --
DO $$
DECLARE
    sridval int;
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE POI ADD COORDS GEOMETRY(POINT);
    sridval := (select srid FROM project_options);
    PERFORM updategeometrysrid('POI', 'coords', sridval);
END $$;
```

Last solution doesn't work with generated columns. Ex:

```sql
ALTER TABLE POI ADD COORDS GEOMETRY(POINT, /*put srid here?*/) generated always as (ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)) stored;
CREATE INDEX COORDS_IDX ON POI USING GIST (COORDS);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `format()` to create your DDL dynamically.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    sridval int;
BEGIN
 sridval := (SELECT srid FROM project_options); 
 EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE poi ADD COLUMN coords geometry(point, %s)',sridval);
END $$;
```

You can also skip the variable declaration by passing the query itself as parameter:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE poi ADD coords geometry(point, %s)',
                 (SELECT srid FROM project_options));
END $$;
```

And

```
DO $$
BEGIN
 EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE poi ADD coords geometry(point, %s) 
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)) STORED;',
                (SELECT srid FROM project_options));
END $$;
```

- This code assumes that `project_options` has a single row

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1f712c077149f44ce016d9dbe8cf8215)

Comment: Very nice, thanks